Extension of restricted determinant
I'm looking for a function $f: (\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, V \in \mathrm{Gr}(m, \mathbb{R}^n)) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with the following properties:

$\forall A, B \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, V \in \mathrm{Gr}(m, \mathbb{R}^n): f(AB, V)=f(A, V)*f(B, V)$
$\forall A \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, V \in \mathrm{Gr}(m, \mathbb{R}^n): \left(\forall v \in V: Av \in V\right) \implies f(A, V) = |\det(A_{|V})|$

By $\mathrm{Gr}(m, \mathbb{R}^n)$ I denote all $m$-dimensional vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Essentially I want to extend the restricted determinant to vector subspaces that are not preserved by $A$ but retain the multiplicative property. I have already considered projections to $V$ and the wedge product but have not made much progress.
I would also be interested in a function $f$ that only fulfills this weaker version of property 1: $\forall A, B \in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, V \in \mathrm{Gr}(m, \mathbb{R}^n): f(AB, V)=g(A, V)*f(B, V)$ where $g: (\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, V \in \mathrm{Gr}(m, \mathbb{R}^n)) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is some other function that does not need to fulfill any additional properties.
Update: I realized that any approach based on mapping matrices to matrices that leave $V$ invariant and then calculating the determinant on $V$ is not going to work, at least for the strong version of property 1. Let $H$ be the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ that leaves $V$ invariant. Then a map $h:\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow H$ would need to have a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ as its kernel due to the first isomorphism theorem and $H$ would need to be isomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R}^n) / \mathrm{ker}(f)$. However, the normal subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ are at most one-dimensional, making this impossible for general $V$.

Here is a proof that such a function $f$ does not exist for the strong version of property 1:
Since $f(A)=f(\sqrt{A})^2$ we have $f(\sqrt{A})=\sqrt{f(A)}$.
In this answer it was shown that the square roots of $I$ take the form $P^{-1} D P$ where $P$ is an arbitrary invertible matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matric where all the diagonal elements are in $\{-1, 1\}$.
Now consider the matrix $A=\mathrm{diag}(1, 1, -1, -1)$, so $n=4$. Since it is a root of the identity matrix which leaves all vector space invariant, we have $f(A, V)=1$ for all $V$ by property 2. Then the following theorem from the paper Products of Similar Matrices by David Witte applies:

Theorem. Let $A \in \operatorname{SL}_n(K)$, where $K$ is a field, and
assume that either $n>2$ or $|K|>3$. If $A$ is not a scalar matrix,
then every element of $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ is a product of matrices
conjugate to $A$.

Since $A$ is not a scalar matrix any matrix in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ can be represented as a product of matrices conjugate to $A$. Since we know that all conjugations of $A$ are roots of the identity, they must all have value 1 and therefore all matrices in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ must have value 1, for all $V$. However, considering the vector space $W$ spanned by $(1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $\mathrm{diag}(2, 1/2, 1, 1) \in \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ we should have $f(\mathrm{diag}(2, 1/2, 1, 1), W) = 2$ by property 2, leading to a contradiction.
